# After a restart I boot into blackscreen with cursor

Tags: windows-explorer, desktop, black-screen-of-death

I have windows 10 64bit for quite a while now.

My system suddenly restarted to apply an update (which I dont know of its specifics). After that windows loads on the logon screen I type my password, log in and am greeted with blackscreen and cursor.

Mouse works
Graphics work
Sound works
Taskmanager works

I can load any program (firefox,games,vlc) and it runs without any problem over the black screen (if i minimize it it still exist as a small rectangle in the bottom of the black screen which I can maximize again) I even can use a file explorer window and copy paste any file or open any file I can even copy paste and run stuff from the "desktop" folder directory, I can search and it works etc

The only thing I cant do is use the task manager to run explorer.exe when I do that nothing happenes (although as I said when I type cmd,msconfig or a directory of an executable lets say firefox it runs without problems)

Also the value of the Shell key (under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon`) exists and is explorer.exe

To cut the long story short everything in my computer works properly as it should except that I dont have any desktop! (or start bar etc) I am able to launch all the programs or open jpegs and documents using the taskmanager... :/

I tried also to reset my installation and it couldnt reset
I tried the DISM and sfc commans (with the proper paramenters ) and they dont work because DISM cant find resources and sfc cant change files..

Chkdisk (and all its parameters) run without outputing any problem

I checked for viruses using linux/rescuedisks (updated) browserbasedscans and my main antivirus bitdefender  etc -also on safe mode- which dont show any results I use to run rkill first (http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/download/rkill/) before each scan and noumerous other reputable malware cleaners like adwcleaner or spybot (even tried in chameleon mode)

I also tried Kaspersky and other ventors worm and rootkit scanners.... nothing

I mean during hours of trial and error I found some things which didnt seem dangerous (like cracks for games etc) but I deleted them anyways and after all the above programs (after restarting and rechecking multiple times under various conditions like safemode,linux etc) I cant find anything any more..

but I still boot into a black screen with a mouse!

Any Ideas since I cant format for the time being because I dont have an extra disk at hand to backup stuff.....and using the taskmanager to open programs etc is a pain in the *****

Please help :(

Comment: Are there any error message in the eventviewer? Any output of you try to start explorer.exe from a shell ?

Comment: Running the Start-Process -Filepath "c:\windows\explorer.exe"  in powershell as an administrator doesnt result into anything (the taskmanager flickers for a split second though after I push enter) but nothing changer no error message nothing appears on "processes" tab etc


As for the eventviewer logs well its hard to check in a sensible timeframe since I did so many things the past day.. some errors I found  are these" Session "ReadyBoot" stopped due to the following error: 0xC0000188"

Comment: Anyting in `eventvwr.msc` ?

Comment: As I said the log entries are immense and cant narrow down anything useful yet... I am more than happy to run any diagnostics you would like and post the log.

Comment: Lots of people are reporting the same problem, apparently caused by a recent Windows update. Can you perform a system restore to a restore point earlier than the last round of updates?

Comment: If I could I would be the happiest guy in the world :P for somereason I dont remember must have wiped out the restorepoint data.... what key phrase did you use to google and find those problems? because as far as I googled I found only "regular" blackscreen of death problems and windows8 to 10 upgrade issues which dont apply to me.

Comment: I have a *verrry* similar problem (after I updated Ubuntu on a seperate hard drive)
The only difference, is for my problem, I can't even run firefox (though I can run several other programs and things). I think it doesn't think I'm fully logged in. Checkdisk did find a few things of interest, but on a drive that doesn't seem related. Did you ever find a solution??